# Get all the records into two temp tables

Tags: oracle

I have a table `TABLE1` and is having more than 10L records.

As part of a requirement, I need to get some records based on the below query to a temp table `TEMP_TABLE1`.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE1 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 tb1 WHERE tb1.repo_id IN (condition A));
```

And,I have to get the rest of the records in to `TEMP_TABLE2` based on the opposite query like,

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE2 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 tb1 WHERE tb1.repo_id NOT IN (condition A));  --added NOT IN
```

My question is, after the first query execution, can we move the rest of the records in the table without a new query which also takes the same time to process.  I am using the same condition to filter in both the cases.

Comment: *more than 10L records* What is `10L`?

Comment: Can you confirm that `10L` is actually 10 Lakhs? If so, 10 Lakhs = 1 million rows

Comment: *My question is, after the first query execution, can we move the rest of the records in the table without a new query which also takes the same time to process. I am using the same condition to filter in both the cases.* Depends on the data. Do a `UNION ALL` of both the select statements and compare the count of it with the `COUNT(*)` on the table.

Comment: So you want to do two operations with the same query? Doesn't sound possible..

Comment: Yes, it is 10 Lakhs.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT ALL 
  WHEN repo_id IN (condition A) THEN INTO temp_table1
  WHEN repo_id not IN (condition A) THEN INTO temp_table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

At first you need to create empty temp_tables:

```
create table temp_table1 as (select * from table1 where 1=0);
create table temp_table2 as (select * from table1 where 1=0);
```

Instead of second condition `WHEN repo_id not IN (condition A) THEN` you can use simply `ELSE` if both sets are excluding.
Examples of [conditional inserts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm) (look at the bottom of page).